# A question from Hoffman's linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

the question is on Section 1.4 exercise 7, it says:

find all solutions of

$$2x_1 - 3x_2 - 7x_3 + 5x_4 + 2x_5 = -2$$

$$x_1 - 2x_2 - 4x_3 + 3x_4 +  x_5 = -2$$

$$2x_1 - 4x_3 + 2x_4 +   x_5 = 3$$

$$x_1 - 5x_2 - 7x_3 + 6x_4 + 2x_5 = -7$$

My answer seems to be that there is no solution, could I ask for a confirmation of this result?

Comment: Just a note: there are many websites that will solve systems of linear equations or, what is the same, row reduce a matrix; some will even show you the steps!

Comment: check this website http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?c=sys

It will solve systems of linear equations along with the steps

Comment: http://matrix.reshish.com/ I think this website can help you.

Comment: Thanks very much! I've never thought such websites exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not correct there is in fact a solution.

The associated matrix is
[image]

Which can be row reduced to

[image]

This is absolutely valid for a solution. Moreover there are infinitely many solutions.